# Is polymorphism possible with List ? How to do it in a constructor?

Tags: c#, polymorphism, covariance

I'm trying to use polymorphism in a constructor but cannot make it work without workaround.

I have :

```
public class A { }
public class B : A { }
```

Why doesn't this work :

```
 IList<B> blist = new List<B> ...
 IList<A> alist = (IList<A>)blist ;
```

When the same without the list works fine:

```
B bt = new B..
A a = (A)b;
```

This is especially annoying when wanting to use a list in a constructor, especially with the c# limitation of calling the base constructor before doing anything else.
which forbid to do this :

```
public X(IList<B> param) : base((IList<A> param))
{}
```

Any way to do it properly without calling a dummy base() and rewriting the constructor completely ?

One way I found is doing :
base(
sections.Select(b => (A) b).ToList()
)

but It feel quite klunky...

**Edit:**

This question emphasis on the construction aspect.

For this case I use a List because the order is important and the amount of elements could vary.
answers on this post and similar post focus on using Array or Enumerable.
However Array is limited when resizing and Enumerable does not guarantee the order.

Comment: what does `X` derive from?

Comment: it derives from another class (Y).  which has a List<A> instead of B in its constructor

Comment: It's a covariance issue. You could use `IReadOnlyList` or `IEnumerable` but then you cannot write to the list. The problem is basically that if you were allowed to cast a `List<B>` to a `List<A>` then you could potentially try to store an `A` into it which is *not* also a `B`, thereby creating a mismtach in types as the underlying `List` object expects a `B`.

Answer (score 1):

Answer is simple, `A` and `B` share an `Is a` relationship, whereas `List<A>` and `List<B>` do not. Hence this is possible with only `A` and `B`:

```
A a = new B();
```

However, using the `Covariance` feature of C# there are a few possibilities which you can explore:

```
IEnumerable<A> a = new List<B>(); // possible due to covariance.
A[] a = new B[]; // or use an array
```

It depends on what you want to do with the list in your constructor/class, whether you just want a collection to enumerate or do you want to add/remove elements.

Of course, last option you already know is to cast each element.

Comment: I see, however Enumerable seems not appropriate in my case, since the order of the elements is important. an array could be better though. 
I might be under-using arrays in c#, probably due to their limitation in c

Comment: `IEnumerable<T>` itself  does not guarantee order, however, if implementation is `List<T>` order will be retained. Other implementations like `HashSet<T>` does not provide order guarantee. If you use only `List<T>` as implementation, you should be good.

Answer (score 0):

There is a Linq Extension `Cast<T>()` that simply casts each element to the given type.

```
IList<B> blist = new List<B>();
IList<A> alist = blist.Cast<A>().ToList();
```

Comment: Definitly a bit better, its clearer.

Answer (score 0):

You'll find that, what does work is,

```
IEnumerable<B> blist = new List<B>();
IEnumerable<A> alist = (IEnumerable<A>)blist;
```

Why? This is because `IEnumerable<out T>` is covariant where as, `IList<T>` is not.

`IList<T>` cannot be covariant because of the `Add` method. So if you want a list instead of a sequence but don't need to mutate the list.

```
IReadOnlyList<B> blist = new List<B>();
IReadOnlyList<A> alist = (IReadOnlyList<A>)blist;
```

works too.